# Через некоторое время Fedora 36 выбрасывает ошибку systemd[1] freezing execution

Tags: linux, fedora

[image: ошибка]
Через неопределенное время, пару раз, выбрасывало из системы и выбивало вот такую ошибку. При установке использовал автоматическое разбиение диска. В чем может быть проблема и как решать?

Comment: Возможно, жёсткий диск умирает?

Comment: Федора как всегда)

Comment: @andreymal систему стаивл на ссд. ему и года то нет

Comment: @Danny ничто не мешает ему умереть и меньше чем через год. У меня был SSD, который самопроизвольно в случайные моменты времени отключался от компьютера и система переставала видеть сама себя - по симптомам похоже на ваш случай

Comment: @andreymal странно, что это случилось сразу как я перешел с винды на линукс. есть какойто универсальный способ проверить это? не мог я кривой установкой федоры сломать ссд?

Comment: Да вроде федора ничего не должна была сломать. Вообще стоит по возможности перехватить логи в момент выбрасывания (например, подключиться к федоре с другого компьютера по ssh, запустить чтение логов ядра `sudo dmesg -wH`, дождаться выбрасывания и почитать последние строки лога) - с ними должно стать понятнее, что происходит на самом деле

Comment: @andreymal только пробую линукс и уже в логи ядра лезть приходится) спасибо за совет. попробую проверить ссд както програмно, может быть на жесткий диск поставлю федору, вдруг правда проблема только в неисправности диска. и попытаюсь смотреть логи. я после выбросов смотрел journalctl > /tmp/logs & gedit /tmp/logs, но совсем дремучий лес